# Can you use WhatsApp API For Business to verify users?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sms

When you begin your business using `Twillio` for *sms verification* is pretty expensive, I was looking for a free/very cheap service for the beginning.

I can see that `Facebook` provides - `Whatsapp business API` and it's unclear if you can already use it to send messages as an individual developer.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/

I can see that `Twillio` also have a `Whatsapp` API which costs money.

Is there a way to send Whatsapp messages today ?

Is there **other** affordable choice to verify new users by `sms` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few Whatsapp non officials API like for example [this one](http://You%20may%20want%20to%20look%20at%20[Google's%20Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/)%20or%20[facebook's][https://www.account-kit.com].%20Yet%20what%20you%20get%20for%20the%20price%20is%20not%20crystal%20clear%20for%20me.) or [this one](https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework). I'm actually also interested in using Whatsapp for sending authentication codes so I'm "collecting" the links for the moment without testing so far. Be careful: it's said quite often that Whatapp is very smart at detecting and blacklisting *non regugar*  usage...

I was also looking at more industrial solutions with [Google's firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/)  or [Facebook's account kit](https://www.account-kit.com). They might be a good alternative yet the pricing model  is not crystal clear for me.